# Need command to lauch Outlook, then close it when I'm done

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm working on C# code to search public folders in Outlook and download any attachments found in the target folder.

The problem is that the program errors out if Outlook is not already up and running on the box.

Here's my code to create a new Outlook object:

```
Outlook.Application p_objOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
```

Unfortunately this will not launch Outlook on the server if it is not already running.

I need the commands to open Outlook at the start of the program, then close it at the end. I've looked around but haven't found anything..

Comment: Can't you use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() to start outlook?

Comment: "will not launch Outlook on the server"??? What "server" are you talking about? Trying to run an Office application on some IIS ASP.Net / other server?

Comment: Why are you using Outlook Automation to read public folder contents?  Why not use Exchange Web Services?  Then you don't need Outlook installed to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean Outlook does not become visible? You need to actually display a folder:

```
Outlook.Application p_objOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
if (p_objOutlook.Explorers.Count == 0)
{
  Outlook.Namespace ns = p_objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  ns.Logon();
  Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.OlFolderInbox)
  inbox.Display();
}
```